# Compilation error when method indirectly refers to assembly

Tags: c#

I have the next solution structure

**Project 1**

Defines interface **IEntity**

**Project 2**

Defines method

```
public void DeleteEntity(short id)
{
    Storages.Delete<IEntity>(id);
}
```

defined in non-generic class derived from generic class, one of its parameters is **IEntity**

**Project 3**

Calls method **DeleteEntity** from project 2.

Project 2 refers to Project 1, Project 3 refers to Project 2. Project 3 can not refer to Project 1, cause it will generate a set of another problems.

So question - why I get error when compiling Project 3:

```
The type 'IEntity' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced
```

And how I can avoid referencing of Project 3 to Project 1

**UPD**

```
public abstract class SearcherFactory<ENTITY_TYPE>
{
...
private IQueryable<ENTITY_TYPE> _query;
...
}

public sealed class ItemFactory : SearcherFactory<IEntity>
{
...
}
```

Comment: Can you add the class definition in project 2? Just need to see how interface from project 1 is used in class in project 2.

Comment: @danish i have added, but i don't know will it be useful

Comment: How are you calling the method in Project 3? Can you share that code as well? Looking at what you have, you do not really need to reference Project 1 in Project 3.

Comment: Well **Project2**'s `public ItemFactory` depends on  `IEntity` so **Project3** will depend on **Project1**

Comment: @Micky so, if I remove generic parameter from SearcherFactory - i will avoid referencing?

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov It seems like you need it. If you don't want **Project3** to see `IEntity` then perhaps make both `ItemFactory` and `SearcherFactory` non-`public` and have **Project3** call some proxy class that doesn't expose `IEntity` to clients such as **Project3**.  This will remove the coupling of **Project1** to **Project3**.  To be honest though, I don't see the problem with **Project1**

Comment: _"it will generate a set of another problems"_ -- your question is incomplete without explaining those problems. It is a fundamental rule of managed code that for every type that is visible to a given assembly and not declared in that assembly, the given assembly must reference the assembly in which that type is visible. You must either encapsulate the use of `IEntity` in #2 so that #3 does not see the type, or #3 must reference #1 where `IEntity` is declared. Your question doesn't contain enough information to provide specific advice on how to achieve either of those strategies.

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, explaining in precise detail why you are unable to get to work either of the two usual ways of addressing the problem.

Comment: I have added an answer to the marked duplicate to ensure that the two most likely solutions to your question are addressed in that question. Really, the best answer is to just add the reference, but if you can't for some reason, you can encapsulate the use of the third library from the second, so that the first does not need the reference to the third. If none of that addresses your concern, please post a new question which includes a good code example, along with a precise explanation of why neither of the usual solutions address your specific problem.